# Accessing Akka Actor context inside a mixin

Tags: scala, akka, mixins, akka-actor

I would like to define a trait that can be mixed in with an Akka actor that schedules a receive timeout after some finite duration.  Here is a sketch of what I want to do...

```
trait BidderInActivityClearingSchedule[T <: Tradable, A <: Auction[T, A]]
    extends ClearingSchedule[T, A] {
  this: AuctionActor[T, A] =>

  context.setReceiveTimeout(timeout)  // can I call this here?

  def timeout: FiniteDuration

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case ReceiveTimeout =>
      val (clearedAuction, contracts) = auction.clear
      contracts.foreach(contract => settlementService ! contract)
      auction = clearedAuction
    case message => this.receive(message)
  }

}


class FancyAuctionActor[T <: Tradable](val timeout: FiniteDuration, ...)
    extends AuctionActor[T, FancyAuctionActor[T]]
    with BidderInActivityClearingSchedule[T, FancyAuctionActor[T]]
```

...but I don't understand when the `context.setReceiveTimeout` will be called.  Will it be called as part of the constructor when the `MyFancyAuctionActor` is called?  Or will it get called earlier and thus throw some kind of error due to fact that `timeout` hasn't been defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest controlling trigger of your schedule using actor's lifecycle event hooks.if you have your trait extend an actor like this:

```scala
trait AuctionActor[T, A] extends Actor
trait BidderInActivityClearingSchedule[T, A] extends AuctionActor[T,A]
```

you'll have access to many of the lifecycle event hooks of the actor such as `preStart()`, `postStop()` and many more.

So you can easily do:

```scala
trait BidderInActivityClearingSchedule[T, A] extends AuctionActor[T,A] {
  override def preStart() = {
    supre.preStart() // or call this after the below line if must.
    context.setReceiveTimeout(timeout)  // can I call this here?
  }    
}
```

**Update**

If you want to implement a stackable mixins structure. you'd do something similar to above.

```scala
//your AuctionActor is now a class as you wanted it
class AuctionActor[T, A] extends Actor

//Look below; the trait is extending a class! it's ok! this means you can 
//only use this trait to extend an instance of AuctionActor class 
trait BidderInActivityClearingSchedule[T, A] extends AuctionActor[T,A]{
  def timeout: FiniteDuration

  //take note of the weird "abstract override keyword! it's a thing!"
  abstract override def preStart() = {
    super.preStart()
    context.setReceiveTimeout(timeout)
  }
}
```

you can have as many of traits that extend your class AuctionActor stacked together.

Comment: Not a bad idea to use actor lifecycle hooks but I don't want to extend Actor I want to keep the trait as a mixin.

Comment: as far as I know the best practiced approach to stackable mixins is having all the mixins extend a base trait. you are practically doing the same thing by having the self type annotation only in your case you are stripping yourself of the advantage of overriding methods. there also is another trick to implementing stackable mixins which I'll describe as an update to answer

Comment: I am familiar with stackable actor pattern and am using it in the library. Perhaps I am being pedantic but I don't like having traits that are clearly mixins extend from Actor.

Comment: Can you explain the abstract override? I have never encountered that before.

Comment: abstract override is for when the trait says "I declare this method, I also give it an implementation, but you must also provide an implementation of your own when extending my trait. so I can override it." it's a bit crazy but makes sense. If you look it calls and depends on super.preStart(), confidentlly calling it and adding up to it's effect. it reminds us of the decorator pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a self-type to require a trait to only be mixed in to Actors.

```
trait MyMixin { self: Actor =>
  println(self.path)
}

trait MyActor extends Actor with MyMixin
```

`MyMixin` isn't *quite* an actor, but it can only be extended by classes that are actors.

Comment: I provided a self type annotation to the mixin in order to enforce the constraint that it must be mixed in with AuctionActor (which extends Actor). Any reason to use "self" rather than "this"?

Comment: You can call it whatever you want.